# Alguien me explica por que al utilizar mi función da 2 argumentos?

Tags: python, tkinter

Alguien me ***explica*** por que al utilizar mi función dobleClick da 2 argumentos?
Mi código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Listbox
ventana1 = tk.Tk()

class editlistBox:
    def __init__(self,nombre,posx,posy,ventana):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.ventana)
        self.listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.dobleClick)
        self.listbox.place(x=posx,y=posy)
        print(nombre)

    def dobleClick(self):
        print("ok")

    def keyEnter(self):
        print("ok")

editlistBox("name",50,50,ventana1)
ventana1.mainloop()
```

Empece hace poco a programar y no encontré en ningún lado la explicación de esto, muchas gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que te topas con el siguiente error cuando el método enlazado es llamado al hacer doble click:

> TypeError: dobleClick() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

que traducido sería:

> Error de tipo: dobleClick() acepta un argumento posicional pero dos fueron dados.

Bien, tu método (porque estrictamente no es una función, sino un método de instancia de la clase `editlistBox`) está definido como:

```
def dobleClick(self):
```

por lo que solo acepta un argumento que es `self`, que es simplemente una referencia a la propia instancia de la clase a la cual el método pertenece y que se pasa de forma automática a todo método de instancia como primer argumento siempre.

Por lo tanto, tal como el error indica `dobleClick` acepta un solo argumento tal como está definido.

Si tienes una función/método que solo acepta un argumento posicional y la llamas usando más de uno tienes el error mencionado, por ejemplo:

```
def foo(arg):
    pass

foo(1, 2)
```

¿Pero por qué dos argumentos fueron enviados a la función?

Uno de ellos es la instancia de la propia clase que como se ha dicho se envía de forma automática, el otro se debe a que cunado se enlaza un evento con su callback mediante `bind`, cuando la función/método es llamado **se le envía el evento responsable de dicha llamada** como argumento. Para verlo más claro, basta con que agregues un argumento y lo imprimas:

```
def dobleClick(self, event):
    print(event)
```

al hacer doble click se imprime algo así:

> `<ButtonPress event state=Mod2 num=1 x=62 y=59>`

esto es muy útil cuando una misma callback se enlaza con varios eventos y se quiere discriminar cual fue el responsable o para conocer datos del propio evento, en este caso por ejemplo las coordenadas donde se ha producido el doble click.

Por lo tanto, tu función debe aceptar este argumento, aunque no lo uses. Si no lo necesitas, por convención se usa `_`. Por cierto, hay otras convenciones con respecto a los nombres de clases y métodos por ejemplo que puedes mirarte en [Convenciones sobre estilo de código Python (PEP-8)](http://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf) y que es conveniente que sigas para que tu código sea más legible:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Listbox


class EditListBox:
    def __init__(self, nombre, posx, posy, ventana):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.ventana)
        self.listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.doble_click)
        self.listbox.place(x=posx, y=posy)

    def doble_click(self, _):
        print("ok")

    def key_enter(self):
        print("ok")


ventana1 = tk.Tk()
EditListBox("name", 50, 50, ventana1)
ventana1.mainloop()
```

O usando herencia en vez de composición:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Listbox


class EditListBox(Listbox):
    def __init__(self, nombre, posx, posy, ventana):
        Listbox.__init__(self, nombre)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.ventana.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.doble_click)
        self.place(x=posx, y=posy)

    def doble_click(self, _):
        print("ok")

    def key_enter(self):
        print("ok")


ventana1 = tk.Tk()
EditListBox(ventana1, 50, 50, ventana1)
ventana1.mainloop()
```